# Apply Angular ng-repeat orderBy and filter to data before ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a table with the following ng-repeat clause..

```
ng-repeat="playlist in playlists | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter : searchExpression(searchText)"
```

I'd like to send the same ordered and filtered list via ajax request.

How do I apply the same filters to..

```
$scope.playlists
```

So that the array matches what is shown in the ng-repeat clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do filter aliasing here and use that alias variable while sending the filtered records to ajax.

```
ng-repeat="playlist in playlists | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse 
              | filter : searchExpression(searchText) as filteredPlaylist"
```

So while using it inside controller you could use

`$scope.filteredPlaylist` object wherever you wanted to pass it.

> Note: this feature has been supported by Anglular 1.3+

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for, thanks!  Do i need to define $scope.filteredPlaylist or will this be auto created?

Comment: @TWilly this will autocreate it for you... don't worry about it.. I think `$parse` service does that Job,,

Comment: do you know how long it takes to populate the results back?  It's empty when i try and iterate over it right after I set $scope.playlists.

Comment: @TWilly how you are going to send this record to ajax?